# How can I create a scatter plot that sizes the points based on a variable?

Tags: microsoft-excel, 3d

Apologies if I didn't use the most accurate title description for my problem but that's what I end up with.

So I have the following dataset which should represents the public pereception in different cities towards some basic services:

```
City/Priority   Roads   Parks   Hospitals        
London           50%     30%      10%      
Paris            40%     20%      40%        
Tokyo            25%     25%      50%        
Rome             20%     30%      50%
```

I'm aiming to have it plotted something like the below with circles sizes proportionally change with the values.

[image]

I though of doing it through scatter plot but no luck. Any idea how to start?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the full answer, but it's a start.

1. "Flatten" your data. The table you posted has two dimensions (city and priority) which makes it hard to plot in Excel. Instead, create a (longer) table that has a column for the city, for the priority and the corresponding value:

```
City     Priority    Value
London   Roads       50%
Paris    Roads       40%
Tokyo    Roads       25%
Rome     Roads       20%
London   Parks       30%
Paris    Parks       20%
Tokyo    Parks       25%
Rome     Parks       30%
London   Hospitals   10%
Paris    Hospitals   40%
Tokyo    Hospitals   50%
Rome     Hospitals   50%
```

2. What you want is called a [Bubble chart](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/present-your-data-in-a-bubble-chart-424d7bda-93e8-4983-9b51-c766f3e330d9) in Excel and it needs numeric data. So you'll need to assign numbers (i.e. ID's) to the city and priority values. Like this:

```
City     City ID     Priority    Priority ID     Value
London   1           Roads       1               50%
Paris    2           Roads       1               40%
Tokyo    3           Roads       1               25%
Rome     4           Roads       1               20%
London   1           Parks       2               30%
Paris    2           Parks       2               20%
Tokyo    3           Parks       2               25%
Rome     4           Parks       2               30%
London   1           Hospitals   3               10%
Paris    2           Hospitals   3               40%
Tokyo    3           Hospitals   3               50%
Rome     4           Hospitals   3               50%
```

3. Create a bubble chart via `Insert` ➡ `Insert Scatter (X, Y) or Bubble chart`:
   [image]
4. Then right click and `Select Data` to add a series with the following settings:

[image]

5. And you're done... sort of:

[image]

I can't figure out a straight forward way of assigning text to the axes of a bubble chart (instead of numbers). Perhaps you can search for `assign text to bubble chart axes excel` to see how to do that.

A True Office® workaround is to delete the axes and add textboxes manually with your city and priority values. Doesn't scale well unfortunately.

If you're not bound to Excel (and can code a bit) you could check out Python with [Plotly](https://plotly.com/python/) or [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) or [Microsoft Power BI](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/desktop/)

Comment: Thank you so much Saaru! I really liked the "flatten" trick. Will see if I could some how change the axes' numbers into text. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: Glad to be of help. You can indicate that this answer is helpful by upvoting it, and if no better answer comes along, you can accept it (give it a green checkmark) in a few days.

Answer (score 0):

A bubble chart is for datasets with three distinct measures. Your table has just one measure (%), so I recommend you don't try to use a bubble chart for this.

Generally with data visualization, you should try to make easy comparisons between related categories.

For your data set, I recommend a clustered bar chart, where comparison is simply between the lengths of the bars.

The bubble chart will make those comparisons more difficult for people viewing the chart.

It's easy to see when a bar is longer or shorter than another bar, even if their magnitudes are very close to one another. If two bubbles are similar in size, it's more difficult to tell which one is bigger or smaller than the other.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. After second thoughts, I went for your visualization method :). Thank you!

Comment: Glad it was useful. If it helped you come to a conclusion, please consider either upvoting or accepting the answer (or both). You can read more about what to do when someone answers your question here: https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers